# How do I add documentation / description to a Header parameter?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

For the `Headers` section, I need to describe what each header parameter / field / entry is. How would I go about doing that?

Currently, my `Headers` section looks like this:

```
+ Headers

        Access-Token: access_token # Server-generated Access Token to authenticate API calls from a user
        User-ID: user_id_from_google # Google-generated ID of each user
        Install-ID: randomly_generated_id # An ID to uniquely identify a device installation for a user
```

I am using `#` to imply that anything after that is a `comment` for that parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not yet possible in the current version of API Blueprint to annotate headers inline.

You could move the description of the headers into the resource or action description. Using a table, you could provide the headers and descriptions. For example:

```
## GET /

### Headers

|Header|Description|
|------|-----------|
| Authorization| The authorization token |

+ Request
    + Headers

            Authorization: Bearer foo

+ Response 204
```

Which would be rendered in Apiary as follows:

[image: Rendered table in an action in Apiary]

In the future, we want to add MSON to headers in API Blueprint. Which will allow you to describe the headers inline (https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint-rfcs/pull/3).

Comment: I guess I'll just stick with my low-tech way since it involves typing less stuff.